# add +1 to year within a text formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a formula which works out my Week Number according to our financial week.

```
=if(ISBLANK(B3), "", if(month(B3) >= 4, TEXT(B3,"YY") & TEXT(WEEKNUM(B3)-13,"0#"), TEXT(B3, "YY") & WEEKNUM(B3)+39))
```

this would make 01/04/18 > 1801

the problem i Have is that our financial year is FY19 so I need this number to say 1901. I cannot figure out how to increment within the text field.. has anyone run into a similar problem before? I'm trying to keep this as one formula so it's as elegant as possible..

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fPYUK2WhsdpFzIFJgKGivSWgbR_WQWYLhmk150erqtI/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet with current formula and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I followed same date format you used in your question, `"DD/MM/YY"`

## Assumptions

1. Your financial week numbering follows the same logic as the WEEKNUM function with the exception that you use **April 1st** as the first day of `week 1` instead of **January 1st**.
2. The year you want to join to the week number is the one associated with the last day of the financial year, **March 31st**, regardless of the actual year of the lookup date.

## Issues to be Overcome

1. February is the only month that has exactly 4 weeks in it, except in a leap year, where it has an extra day.
2. The first day of the calendar year, may fall anywhere in a week, including on the last day.
3. Sheets assigns 53 or 54 weeks depending on the year.
4. You are consistently starting your fiscal year 3 months, **not** 13 weeks, after the start of the calendar year, as some fiscal years will start 12 weeks later. 
   For example,

   ```
   =WEEKNUM("01/04/17")       =WEEKNUM("01/04/18")
   =13                        =14
   ```

## My Approach

I mimic the approach that Sheets uses for its WEEKNUM function adjusted for your fiscal year:

1. Day 1 of Week 1 falls on **April 1** (not Jan. 1)
2. Day 1 of Week 2 falls on the first Sunday that follows **April 1**, even if that means (which it typically does) that Week 1 is less than 7 days long.
3. Subsequent weeks start every Sunday until it starts again on **April 1**.

```
=LET(dt,K39,
  fs,DATE(YEAR(dt)-(MONTH(dt)<4),4,1),
  seq,SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(EDATE(fs, 11),)-fs,1,fs),
  arr,{fs; FILTER(seq, WEEKDAY(seq)=1)},
  RIGHT(YEAR(fs)+1,2)& 
  TEXT(VLOOKUP(dt, {arr, SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr))},2,1),"0#"))
```

1. `dt` is the lookup date
2. `fs` is the **f**iscal **s**tart date with the year calculated by subtracting 1 from `YEAR(dt)` if `dt` is a date in months 1-3.
3. `seq` is a sequence of dates starting from `fs` through to the last day of the fiscal year.
4. `arr` is an array of all the first days of the week. FILTER is used to return `seq` if `WEEKDAY(seq)=1` and `fs` is manually added to the top of the array regardless what weekday it is.
5. The Fiscal year is joined to the week number. The week numbers are generated using SEQUENCE and manually attached as the second column of `arr`, which creates a sorted week number lookup table that VLOOKUP can use to retrieve the week number associated with the biggest date in `arr` that `dt` is equal to or less than.

If your week starts on a weekday other than Sunday, simply change the `1` in `WEEKDAY(seq)=1` of the formula for `arr` to whatever day your week starts with, eg. `2` for Monday, `7` for Saturday, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but finally got it, I had to use ABS (absolute sum) before the YEAR sum and +1 writing a script in python tipped me off when I had to call .astype(str) in pandas.

```
=if(ISBLANK(B3), "", if(month(B3) >= 4, TEXT(B3,"YY") & TEXT(WEEKNUM(B3)-13,"0#"), TEXT(B3, "YY") & WEEKNUM(B3)+39))


=if(ISBLANK(B2), "", if(month(B2) >= 4, ABS(TEXT(B2,"YY")+1) & TEXT(WEEKNUM(B2)-13,"0#"), TEXT(B2, "YY") & WEEKNUM(B2)+39))
```

this gives me 1901 as expected.